# nginx load balancer - how to preserve full original url in upstream?

Tags: nginx

nginx 1.7.9 on linux

Issue:

When using nginx, the Web servers see all requests as coming over http, even when they come in via https.

Using IIS request tracing, we see the request coming in like this, even when the outside (from browser) request is `https://myapp.com:443/appdir/`:

```
RequestURL="http://myapp.com:80/appdir/"
```

But on our hardware load balancer (which we are trying to phase out), it comes correctly as:

```
RequestURL="https://myapp.com:443/appdir/"
```

The app needs to see the https, it depends on it. (It tries to force connections to secure.)

We know about using X-Forwarded-Proto and the like to tell the app that the request came in via ssl, however part of the app is build around the request itself, and we may not be able to modify it.

The hardware load balancer can "do it all" -- terminate ssl, and send "pretend" requests back to the app (over port 80) that appear to be requests to https.

How do I get nginx to pass the full, unchanged, request url back to the servers?

Config:

```
http {

upstream sandbox_site {
    least_conn;
    # we pipe to back end on port 80 only, so that nginx handles all ssl
    server 192.168.2.16:80 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=60s;  # sbox3-site is .2.16
}

server {
    # This is sandbox.myapp.com block **************************************
    listen 192.168.2.27:80;
    server_name sandbox.myapp.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://sandbox_site;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    # This is SSL version of sandbox.myapp.com block **************************************
    listen 192.168.2.27:443 ssl;
    server_name sandbox.myapp.com;

    ssl_certificate      new-sandbox-myapp-com.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key  new-sandbox-myapp-com.key;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sandbox_site;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;            
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `The hardware load balancer can "do it all" -- terminate ssl, and send "pretend" requests back to the app (over port 80)` - perhaps look at the actual request sent over the wire to determine how it's doing that. Either there's a header it's setting (such as `ORIGINAL_URI`) or it's doing something different than you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have two choices:

- either you are offloading SSL, like you are doing it now, then you may tell your backends that the request actually was received with SSL (if it was):

  ```
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  ```

  but this surely means you have to adjust the code, so it handles that header.
- or, if no code modification is allowed, you can stop offloading SSL, and actually proxy pages from backends via it.

  So this is how the SSL sandbox block would look like:

  ```
  location / {
      proxy_pass https://sandbox_site;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;            
  }
  ```

However, this second way is way redundant: you see, you actually do still offload SSL, but then assemble the SSL request again, even when it comes through your trusted network. All it does - just adding unnecessary conversion.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, not a nice choice at all.  I am familiar with the "X-Forwarded-Proto" as part of our app (the old part) uses it to detect secure channel. But the new part depends on the request (possibly due to js/backend division of responsibility, not sure, I do the network, not the app). The hardware load balancer can "do it all" (terminate ssl, and pass full requests back over port 80). Is it time to drop nginx and look at haproxy?

Comment: I don't think so, nginx it better as load balancer when it comes to HTTP. Furthermore I am not sure how IIS handles it. To my knowledge, passing https request to port 80 should either rise an error, or should mean that port 80 is SSL-enabled. However, IIS/Windows is not really my area of expertise. Finally I should say that I don't see a way to archieve your goal on haproxy (though it does provide similar possibilities to the mentioned above ones).

Comment: You are correct. On closer inspection, the hardware lb is not doing what we thought. Code mods... here we come...